# Allowing or deny a permission crash the app android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to implement the lastest permission system for an Android app. I have the dialog that pops up when I trigger a button (this is an expected behavior) but as soon as I tap on Allow or Deny, the app crash but it looks like the permissions were correctly granted or denied (depending on the tapped button).

This is the onClick method:

```
public void okGetItLocation(View view){

    Log.d(TAG, "BTN FIRED");
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        Log.d(TAG, "WE HAVE TO SHOW AN EXPLANATION");
        // Create a LocationPermissionError fragment
        NoLocationPermissionsFragment noLocationPermissionsFragment = new NoLocationPermissionsFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, noLocationPermissionsFragment)
                .commit();

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    }else {

        Log.d(TAG, "POPUP SHOWN");

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

        // REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

And this is the method that get the user choice:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Log.d(TAG, "PERMISSIONS GRANTED");

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "PERMISSIONS DENIED");

                // Create a LocationPermissionError fragment
                NoLocationPermissionsFragment noLocationPermissionsFragment = new NoLocationPermissionsFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, noLocationPermissionsFragment)
                        .commit();

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

My log:

```
03-25 12:19:38.673 2944-2944/com.danajeremy.egullapireading D/FIRSTACTIVITY: BTN FIRED
03-25 12:19:38.673 2944-2944/com.danajeremy.egullapireading D/FIRSTACTIVITY: POPUP SHOWN
03-25 12:19:39.375 2944-2963/com.danajeremy.egullapireading E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeb16d800
```

Comment: Here you go, just added it

Comment: That is not a Java stack trace. If your app is crashing, there will be a stack trace.

Comment: There is no stack trace printed after these lines even in the verbose log level.

Comment: Nobody has an idea on what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who'd like to know, it was because I had added NOHISTORY on my MainActivity (in the Manifest). Now it works like a charm.

Comment: A little bit OverKill - Working but not compliante with most of the app: NoHistory
Specify whether an activity should be kept in its history stack. If this attribute is set, then as soon as the user navigates away from the activity it will be finished and they will no longer be able to return to it.